# UPDATE statement with associative array in PHP returns Notice

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem updating my table with data loaded from Excel sheet into associative array, here is my snippet:

```
    foreach ($priceList as $sku => $price) {

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE product SET price = :price WHERE sku = :sku;");
    $stmt->bindParam(':price',  $price);
    $stmt->bindParam(':sku', $sku);
    $stmt->execute();
    echo 'Table has been updated...';

 }
```

After executing, the prices in the table won't update and I get a notice: "Notice: Array to string conversion..."

var_dump of my array:

```
array (size=1768)
      '32732eglo' => string '27.25' (length=5)
```

The sku column in my table is VARCHAR and the price column is DECIMAL, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: as you can read, you are trying to use an array like a string. $sku or $price are array instead of string

Comment: Your output of the array looks as though you have modified it - can you give (the first part) of the actual output.

Comment: @NigelRen array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=1768)
      '32732eglo' => string '27.25' (length=5)
      '97475eglo' => string '57.51' (length=5)
      '97476eglo' => string '0.00' (length=4)
      '97936eglo' => string '0.00' (length=4)
      '97906eglo' => string '329.17' (length=6) I'm also gonna consider the above comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your sample output it looks as though you have an extra layer of array...

```
array (size=1) 0 => 
         array (size=1768) 
               '32732eglo' => string '2...
```

so use...

```
foreach ($priceList[0] as $sku => $price) {
```

Comment: Just realised that and found where I made the mistake as you wrote the comment.

Answer (score 0):

So I had an array within array which happened by using

```
$priceList[] = array_combine($skuArray,$pricesArray);
```

I fixed it by declaring the array before this row:

```
$priceList = array();
$priceList = array_combine($skuArray,$pricesArray);
```

or simply in one line:

```
$priceList = array_combine($skuArray,$pricesArray);
```